# int to store var type as well in c#

Tags: c#

I have a model:

```
public class KPIResults
{
   public virtual string Title { get; set; }
   public virtual int Total { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week6 { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week5 { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week4 { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week3 { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week2 { get; set; }
   public virtual  int Week1 { get; set; }

   public virtual string stringWeek6 { get; set; }
   public virtual string stringWeek5 { get; set; }
   public virtual string stringWeek4 { get; set; }
   public virtual string stringWeek3 { get; set; }
   public virtual string stringWeek2 { get; set; }
   public virtual string stringWeek1 { get; set; }
}
```

In my reporting repository i have:

```
 int strfound = 0;
 string str = "Number";
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
    string title = dr["Title"].ToString();
    int total = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"]);
    if (dr["Week6"].contains("Number")  //synntacs not right?
        var week6 = dr["strWeek6"]
    end

    or do this:
    strfound = str.IndexOf(dr);  //syntacs not right?
    if (strfound == 0)
    {
         var week6 = dr["strWeek6"]
    } 
    var week6 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week6"]);
    var week5 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week5"]);
    var week4 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week4"]);
    var week3 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week3"]);
    var week2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week2"]);
    var week1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Week1"]);

    results.Add(new KPIResults() {Title = title, Total = total, Week6 = week6, Week5 = week5, Week4 = week4, Week3 = week3, Week2 = week2, Week1 = week1});

  }
  return results;
```

I should maybe try and do a string search but my code in the is is not right. I search for ways to handle string but not clear.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it generates strings like"? Currently your question is *very* unclear. It's not obvious where you're getting the data from, or what that data really is...

Comment: You can't store a string in an int. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you should fix your data? Or make the model properties of type string.

Comment: Did you check the values for `dr["Weekn"]` when this happens, seems weird that Convert to int is returning strings for you ! !

Comment: Is it normal that you receive strings instead of expected ints? You won't store anything but `int` into int-typed field...should you wrap those fields in `object`..though I'm not sure how mvc will utilize them in views then

Comment: As soon as the foreach processes the strings and want to store it as type in the program fails. The foreach gets the data from running a stored procedure. let me see what I can do :) thanks

Comment: I edited my OP but not sure which if would be best and syntax also wrong? thanks

Comment: not to worry i fixed it..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat unclear on what you are trying to do, to answer your question, `All I want to know is it possible to cast the var type to be stored as an int or the other way around?` No.

I think your best bet would be to use `string` then it will be able to hold text and numbers. You could do a regex test to check if it contains text, then if not, convert the number it stores to an `int` for you to work this.

Or just make a better model that will include all the sections you need.

You could also use `.GetType()` to return the type of `var`.

**Update**

Ok, it looks like you are now trying to detect if `dr["Week6"]` contains a `string` or an `int`. One way to go about this is:

```
int number;
if(int.TryParse(dr["Week6"], out number))
    var week6 = dr["strWeek6"]
```

If `dr["Week6"]` can be converted into an `int`, then the `if` statement is `true` and `number` will contain the value of `dr["Week6"]`.

Here is the metadata for `int.TryParse`:

> Summary:
>        Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer
>        equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.
>
> Parameters:    s:
>        A string containing a number to convert.
>
> result:
>        When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent
>        to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the
>        conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null, is not
>        of the correct format, or represents a number less than System.Int32.MinValue
>        or greater than System.Int32.MaxValue. This parameter is passed uninitialized.
>
> Returns:
>        true if s was converted successfully; otherwise, false.